# Live Analytics User data in CMS or Framework

Tags: php, session, asynchronous, analytics

I'm trying to use analytics to determine content being served to visitors from a CMS. As far as I can tell there is no API for Google Analytics that allows you to retrieve a users browsing history.

I understand you can store this into the users session, or roll  your own logging of user visits, but I'm more interested in analytics platforms that offer and interface to access this data.

Is anyone aware of an analytics platform that allows you to programmatically retrieve the users data?

The other important aspect would be whether the user data can still be retrieved even if the storing of that data is done asynchronously - which would be needed to keep web app responsive.

Comment: Something like this http://piwik.org/docs/javascript-tracking/ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In analytics platform you have several solutions. The most common in open source is Piwik http://piwik.org/

It offers an API and js tracking systems : http://piwik.org/docs/javascript-tracking/

Comment: Thanks, this led me to the answer: http://piwik.org/docs/real-time/#toc-real-time-analytics-api

Answer (score 1):

You can set this up indirectly in Google Analytics, by using [funnels and goals](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?answer=55515). Set a few predetermined paths of website pages, and have the visitors walking these paths reach a goal.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://www.openwebanalytics.com/. A might be a little bit of overkill for your situation, but if you need a customized need, it should be the right fit. If you're a developer or have access to one then you're set.